# Fashion Clothing images Dataset with image description

Tags: dataset, image-classification

I am searching for Fashion Clothing image dataset where each image is associated with description. Basically description should contains all information about cloth. like -

```
image_01.jpg - red shirt has collar with long-sleeves.
```

Is there any good source to collect these type of dataset ??

Answer (score 1):

You can check Fashion10000 dataset released by Delft University of Technology [here](http://www.st.ewi.tudelft.nl/~bozzon/fashion10000dataset/)